# Mapping InputDevice to BluetoothDevice

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

When a BLE HID device is added by Android for accepting inputs for InputEvents etc, I can see that InputDevice shows name, Pid and Vid, but is there any way I could map it to an individual BLE device?

Specifically, if there are more than one of BLE HID devices connected of same type, and all are in InputDevice list, how do I map which InputDevice is which BluetoothDevice?

Are there any methods in BluetoothDevice that can return me an InputDevice or Input-device's id or descriptor? Or are there any methods in InputDevice that can return a BluetoothDevice or address? Reflection is not a problem.

Comment: I found that BluetoothProfileProxy for BT_PROFILE_INPUT_DEVICE (provided by ServiceListener.onServiceConnected() ) has a method getConnectedDevices() which returns a list of all BT HID input devices currently connected. Each one of these should map to one InputDevice, but I still don't know how to establish that relation.